# How to change the Winston plot range of x after evaluation in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia

```
using Winston

x=[0:0.1:2pi];

y=sin(x)

plot(x,y)
```

When I change the range of `x`, I got the same result as the old range.

Comment: What do you  mean by "same result"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also have to re-calculate y and generate a new plot:

```
using Winston
x=[0:0.1:2pi];
y=sin(x)
plot(x,y)
```

Generates the first plot and then

```
x=[0:0.1:4pi]; #Re-define x
y=sin(x)       #Calculate new y
plot(x,y)      #Generate new plot
```

will generate a new plot.